# In the English language or about the English language?

Tags: word-choice

> Ĝi estas angla filmo.

Does this mean that the language of the movie is English (understood by English speakers), or does this mean that the film is about the English language (the film may be in any language but is talking about the English language)?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it would have anything to do with the language. According to PIV, angla is "Rilata al angloj aŭ al Anglio", which is the general adjective "english" (english food, english culture, english kings). Now an english film is very likely (almost certain) to be in the english language but I think you'd want to say "anglalingva filmo" or "filmo en La Angla" for English-language film.

Comment: Thanks. What if someone said "Esperanta filmo"? Since there is no esperanto country, how would this be interpreted?

Answer (score 3):

It can mean that the movie is English, i.e. from England, or it may mean that it is in English. It cannot mean a movie about English, in this case you would have to say something like *Ĝi estas filmo pri la angla lingvo.*